# Why is TextInputEditText producing this error?

Tags: java, android, fonts

I've been trying to change the `fontfamily` of my application to advent pro. The problem is only my `textinputedittext` produces this error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Font not found C:\Users\owner\AndroidStudioProjects\Application\app\src\main\res\font\advent_pro_medium.ttf
```

Everything works fine on buttons and `textviews`. I've also tried using `edittext`, it does not produce this error but the `fontfamily` doesn't get applied. I have my font in the exact same directory that the error states, so why is `textinputedittext` producing this error? Below is the code of my `textinputedittext`..

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/etJoinCode"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/advent_pro"
        android:hint="@string/join_code"
        android:textColor="#ffff"
        android:textColorHint="#ffff"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
```

Comment: remove this line and try  android:fontFamily="@font/advent_pro"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `android:fontFamily="@font/advent_pro"` in your xml code .

**1.create a new `fonts` directory in the `assets` directory and put the `advent_pro_medium.ttf` font file here.**

**2.You can change to this .**

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(v.getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/advent_pro_medium.ttf");
etJoinCode.setTypeface(tf);
```

Comment: This worked, thank you. Kind of annoying that I can't change it in xml

Comment: I did not how to  do it .You also can do like this .And `fontFamily` did not work in low version.